# How to specify commandline arguments in settings.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am compiling an Android project with gradle and want to run `-x lint` with every build.

is it possible to use settings.gradle to automatically add this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the following to the root project's `build.gradle`:

```
gradle.startParameter.excludedTaskNames << "lint"
```